# How to extend a line segment in ARKit 2/SceneView

Tags: swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I have two points in space, and want a *third* point that is an extension of the first two points by some multiplier - extending the line segment. How would I do that in Swift4 - how would I get `x2`, `y2`, `z2` below?

```
    distanceMultiplier: Float   = 1.2

    var segmentStart = simd_float3.init()

    segmentStart.x = X0
    segmentStart.y = Y0
    segmentStart.z = Z0

    var segmentEnd1 = simd_float3.init()

    segmentEnd1.x = X1
    segmentEnd1.y = Y1
    segmentEnd1.z = Z1

    var segmentEnd2 = simd_float3.init()


    //segmentEnd1.x2 = foo
    //segmentEnd1.y2 = foobar
    //segmentEnd1.z2 = barfoo
```

Answer (score 2):

First, it's purely a choice of style, but you don't need to write everything longhand. `typename.init()` can always be abbreviated as `typename()`, for example. And the SIMD types all work without the `simd_` prefix in Swift. The vector types have elementwise initializers, too:

```
let segmentStart = float3(x0, y0, z0)
```

Anyhow, the real question here is just basic math. A vector that describes the (length of) line segment between two points is the difference of the two points:

```
let segmentLength = segmentEnd1 - segmentStart
```

To describe the whole segment, you need to know either its origin and its length (two vectors) or its start and end points (also two vectors). If you have either of those pairs, you can convert between them.

```
assert(segmentEnd1 == segmentStart + segmentLength)
```

If you want to extend a segment, you'll want the origin + length representation.

```
let segmentLength2 = segmentLength * multiplier
```

Once you have that, you can convert back to start/endpoint representation:

```
let segmentEnd2 = segmentStart + segmentLength2
```

It's pretty easy to see once illustrated (here in 2D, but the math is the same no matter how many dimensions you have):

[image]